# Does std::is_constructible work with arguments that are convertible to parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang

Does `std::is_constructible<T, Arg1>` work if `Arg1` is a type that is convertible to a valid one-parameter constructor for `T`?  It appears to work when the type has a non-templated conversion operator, but does not work (under some compilers) if the conversion operator is templated.

In the below example, the final `static_assert` fails under GCC 7.2 and clang 5.0, but passes under MSVC 19.  Is there undefined behavior in here, or is one of the compilers misbehaving?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
{
    foo(int) {}
    foo(int, int) {}
};

struct converts
{
    template <class T>
    operator T(){}
};

int main()
{
    // These compile
    foo f1(converts());
    foo f2(converts(), converts());
    static_assert(std::is_constructible<foo, converts, converts>::value, "foo(converts(), converts())");
    // This line doesn't
    static_assert(std::is_constructible<foo, converts>::value, "foo(converts())");
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/g/EcFqMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a Most Vexing Parse issue. Since the line `foo f1(converts())` *can* be seen as a declaration of a function `f1`, the compiler *must* treat it as a declaration. If you switch the parentheses for braces, the first line stops compiling:

```
int main()
{
    foo f1{converts()}; // Now broken
    foo f2{converts(), converts()};
}
```

<sup>[Live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/GWwT8Z)</sup>

The error message helpfully tells us that the compiler can't determine whether to call `foo(int)`, or `foo(const foo&)`, or `foo(foo&&)`, as `converts` could also be converted into `foo` with its templated conversion operator.

When you use the parentheses, [we can see](https://godbolt.org/g/NSjTDP) by using `decltype` that the compiler sees `f1` as a declaration of a function of type `foo(converts(*)())` – a function returning `foo`, which takes one argument which is a function pointer.

Comment: Interesting, so it appears MSVC is incorrectly accepting the program.  Thanks!

Comment: @jnewman Maybe you're using an old version of MSVC, because it [does reject the program](https://godbolt.org/g/EFqZx8)